# Distributing the Visual C++ Runtime Libraries (MSVCRT)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an ATL/WTL project developed using Visual Studio 2008 and up until now I have been statically linking with the CRT libraries, avoiding the need to ship them.  However, I now need to consider using the dynamic libraries (DLL) instead - in order to reduce the size of the code and because I want to use the excellent [crashrpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) tool (which requires you dynamically link to the CRT.)

Now, MS supply both a stand-alone installer (vcredist_x86.exe) and an MSM package but this is no good for me for two reasons:

- I am not using an MSI based installer (I am using InnoSetup).
- My application installs on a limited user account and the vcredist_x86.exe installer will not work.

Therefore I want to ship the CRT DLLs and install then in my applications program folder.  Now, this is something you can do as I found the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/martynl/archive/2005/10/13/480880.aspx#488328) by Martyn Lovell, the MSVC Libraries Development Lead that says:

> However, if you want to
>   install-applocal, you should make sure
>   that your application has a manifest,
>   and then copy the whole of this folder
>   into your EXE directory:
>
> X:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   8\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC80.CRT
>
> and other folders if you use more than
>   the CRT. Make sure you include the
>   manifest.

Just want I am after - except I don't understand this part:

> make sure that your application has a manifest

My question is - how do I create an application manifest that references the CRT DLLs I want to use?  The only manifest information my projects currently use is the following (which ensures the app uses v6 of the Common Controls):

```
/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"
```

Can someone provide me with instructions on how to work the manifest magic using Visual Studio 2008?  There is a Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest file in my Visual Studio VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT folder - do I need to use this somehow?

Note: This is a similar - but different - question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073509/should-i-redistribute-msvcrt-dll-with-my-application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio will generate the correct manifest for you when you pass the /MD flag.

Comment: So other than changing my 'Runtime Library' setting on the 'C/C++ -> Code Generation' page, I don't need to do anything else (other than ship the CRT DLLs of course!)?

Comment: Correct, AFAIK. (As long as you're not trying to deploy a debug version with `/MDd`)

Comment: Look in the build directory of your project, you'll see the manifest file.