# CEFSharp Project executable file published by Visual Studio fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, chromium-embedded, crash

I was trying to publish a **CEFSharp** project through **Visual Studio 2013 Cummunity**. The **.NET version** I used is 4.5( tried 4.0 already and it failed). The program can run smoothly under model **Release 64x** model. However, when I tried to publish it to **an executable format** and run it, the executable file crashed and I got the following message error message.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: CEFRenderTest.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    55b166ca
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18869
  Fault Module Timestamp:   556366fd
  Exception Code:   e0434352
  Exception Offset: 000000000000b3dd
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 367e
  Additional Information 2: 367e805d0e7c1ec3f63b05bb5ce5c416
  Additional Information 3: baed
  Additional Information 4: baed2f50fa8c90ffc9d41aca75222fe2

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Anyone familiar with VS and CEFSharp potential knows why?

Comment: What is the difference between running the "model Release x64" and "publish to an executable format and run it"? These are essentially the same process, are you running it on different computers? Have you tried to attach the debugger when you run it?

Comment: By publish I take it your referring to `ClickOnce`? If that's the case, then you need to include the `unmanaged` dll's in your project, something `ClickOnce` doesn't do by default. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/500#issuecomment-57918525 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841585/deploying-wpf-application-with-3rd-party-dlls/24287807#24287807 for some information on a solution.