# WPF application using CEFSharp Web Browser crashing in clickonce release

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, cefsharp

I have a simple WPF application which works fine in debug but when i do a clickonce release its crashing when trying to load the CEFSharp web browser

I have a login page where the user then clicks open browser once clicked i get the following error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'MyProject.Views.CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl' that matches the
>   specified binding constraints threw an exception.

[image: Xaml Error when creating an instance of the UserControl]

```
> <TabItem Header="Web Page" Name="CefWebPage">
>                 <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0">
>                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                         <ColumnDefinition Width="871*"/>
>                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                     <views:CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl x:Name="CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl"></views:CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl>
>                 </Grid>
>             </TabItem>
```

> Exception: Cannot create an instance of "CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl".
>
> TargetInvocationException: Exceptionhas been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core,
>   Version=45.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

code behind

```
    public partial class CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public CefSharpWebBrowserUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.PackLoadingDisabled = true;
            WebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            WebBrowser.Address = "www.google.com";
            BrowserGrid.Children.Add(WebBrowser);
        }

        public ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ClickOnce` by default doesn't include the `unamanged` resources that `CefSharp` requires. There are many issues that already address this topic.

Here are a couple of useful ones

- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1314
- [Deploying WPF Application with 3rd Party DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841585/deploying-wpf-application-with-3rd-party-dlls/24287807#24287807)

Searching the `GitHub` project is always an excellent resource.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?q=clickonce&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

You also need to make sure `VC++ Redist` is installed on your target machines. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#version-branches for more info one which `VC++` version you require.

In general, please try searching `GitHub`/`StackOverflow` before posting your question.

Answer (score -4):

Would you mind trying to add the https:// at the WebBrowser.Address?

So from:

```
WebBrowser.Address = "www.google.com";
```

To have:

```
WebBrowser.Address = "https://www.google.com";
```

This [post](http://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/) might also help you.

Comment: That would be better served as a comment, in addition, it is not the problem he is describing. From his question it seems like the project runs fine in Visual Studio but crashes when it is installed through click once.