# CefSharp.winfors doesn't run on Windows 7

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I'm working on a project that include the sample code of CefSharp.MinimalExample.Winforms. 
I'm on Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2015 and the latest redist.
Once I've published my app, I tried to run it on Windows 7 (with the framework 4.5 installed on it) but it doesn't works and I do not know why.
I tried to use also the redist 2012 update 4 on Visual Studio 2015, but it didn't work.
Any suggestions about it?
Thanks

Comment: How does this question differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225222/clickonceinstall-cefsharp-winforms-problems?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#release-branches to determine `VC++ version`

Comment: I tried to use VC  2012, but it didn't work. What did I want do know is this:
To use another VC++ version, do I have to install another Visual Studio? Or may I install this version on my Visual studio 2015?? Is it supported?
Thanks

Comment: Anyway I installed the supported package (vc 2013) and I tried to install also Visual studio 2013 express. I tried to publish the app using visual studio 2013, but it doesn't work. :\

Comment: The latest release (`45.0.0`) uses `VC++ 2013`, you only need to install the redist. If your using an older version you then need `VC++ 2012`. Make sure you get the correct architecture, e.g. `x86`. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003

Comment: Yes, i did this. I downloaded first the vc 2012 and then i tried it on visual studio 2015: nothings. Then I downloaded the vc 2013 and tried it again before on visual studio 2015 and then on visual studio 2013: nothings. It doesn't work on windows 7. What do i have to do??

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using? Are you distributing as `x86` or `x64`? For clarity `VC++ Redist` needs to be installed on any machine you wish to run `CefSharp` on.

Comment: I'm using version 45 on distributing x86. 
What do you mean? I have to install vc++ redist also on windows 7 where do i have to run the program?? :\

Comment: Anyway, I'm on an x64 architecture and i wish to run my program on windows 7 on an x86 architecture. So what I did, is to publish the program in x86 to have the program in the right architecture in windows 7. Is it right? (all this using vc++ 2013)

Comment: Development architecture is largely irrelevant. If your deploying to `x86` then obviously you select `x86`. You need to install `VC++ 2013 Redist` on the `Windows 7` machine.

Comment: That's incredible. So, is this a primary requirement to run a Cefsharp program on Windows 7 ? Independently from the architecture? *_*

Comment: To run on any version of Windows `CefSharp` will require `VC++ Redistributable` to be installed, not just limited to `Windows 7`. You can run an `x86` app on `x64` windows, obviously you can't run an `x64` app on `x86` windows. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/NuGet/Readme.txt#L17

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003, read under `More Information`

Comment: Finally i did it. It works. Thanks a lot man !!! :)