# CefSharp.Wpf - App not working on Windows 7 without installing Visual Studios

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded

I have a `Wpf` `Application` that uses `CEF` to show web content in the application. It is working on every system, but Windows 7. There the `Application` will work until i get to a UserControl where `CEF` is embedded.

It just crashes when i get to this point and I can't debug, because the Visual Studio Installation fixes my problem.

So I started this morning and tried this:

- used [Dependency Walker 2](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)
- Updated IE
- Updated DirectX
- Updated .NET Framework
- Went through the [Output files description table (Redistribution)](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution))

I found many ClickOnce Problems (like [this](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1314) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225222/clickonceinstall-cefsharp-winforms-problems)) - but i don't deploy it like that at the moment. I just want to make it work by copy deployment.

Currently the Installation of VS2015 (only tried this version) fixes my problem - but I don't know what it installs to make it work. Do you know?

If it helps - i get this `Problem signature`

- Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3
- Problem Signature 01: MyWpfApp.WpfApplication.exe
- Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
- Problem Signature 03: 592c4983
- Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
- Problem Signature 05: 4.6.81.0
- Problem Signature 06: 5584f3d7
- Problem Signature 07: 22fd
- Problem Signature 08: 0
- Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
- OS Version:      6.1.7601.2.1.0.320.65
- Locale ID:         1031
- Additional Information 1:          b516
- Additional Information 2:          b51634feea5bd8f1418ce636d6fff953
- Additional Information 3:          f184
- Additional Information 4:          f184d6de0b91a1a4c60646f94c577d0c

My next step will be - checking what is installed with Visual Studio 2015. My current guess is that there is a missing VC++ Redistributable.

Comment: Check the target framework your application and assembly were compiled for. Vanilla Win7 was only coming with .NET 3.5. The installer of VS updates .NET to the required version 4.x if it was not yet intalled (which one exactly would depend on the VS version). Especially, check the .NET requirments for the cefSharp version you are using...

Comment: I am using a WPF - Application that requires 4.52. So I have to install it bevore even starting the application.

Comment: Have you remembered to install the VC++ 2012/2013 redistributable? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019667

Comment: Note the Problem Signature 05. It says "4.6.81.0". Does it look familiar? It makes me think that at least for the "MyWpfApp.WpfApplication.exe" executable the target framework is 4.6 and not 4.5.2. (The exe seems to demand the PresentationFramework assembly of this framework version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CefSharp cover this on their [FAQ](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies) and it is very likely a missing VCRedist.

You can include the redist MSI with your installer if you have one or simply drop the required libraries into your archive for xcopy style deploys