# could not load file or assembly 'cefsharp.core '

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, cefsharp

I created a winform applocation c# and using cefsharp. project works on dev machine, but it does not run on other machines. other machines shows the following error:

> could not load file or assembly 'cefsharp.core 63.0.3.0' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

how should I send the assembly to other machines?
I created a publish version of project, but it does not create the assembly on other machines.

[please help me to fix this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNWbr.png)

Comment: You need to copy the dll file/(s) in the project folder (where ever you're getting the executable from) as well as the executable itself.

Comment: its all ready copy but is same error

Comment: all referenced dlls are not copied or using the wrong version.

Comment: Could you show us what the assembly's directory looks like on the other machine?

Comment: Probably duplicated, too many related results https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+could+not+load+file+or+assembly+cannot+find+the+file+specified

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39675335/4583726

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)