# Cannot get CefSharp to work on user computers even though I've followed distribution instructions (as far as I know)

Tags: c#, clickonce, cefsharp

I have a WinForms application that I'm writing with Visual Studio 2017 using CefSharp 75.1.14.  The application runs correctly on my computer, but I'm struggling to get it to work on other computers.  I've tried bundling the CefSharp libraries with ClickOnce, and I've also tried copying the entire `bin\x64\release` directory to user computers.

In order to try to make ClickOnce work, I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225222/clickonceinstall-cefsharp-winforms-problems).  Here's what my ClickOnce Prerequisites look like after following those instructions.

[image]

On some computers, the installed application will work.  On some, it'll partially work.  On some, it'll crash as soon as it loads.

For instance, on Windows Server 2012, the application runs, but then I get this crash when I close it.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: Test.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:  f1a0272b
  Fault Module Name:  StackHash_5374
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.19478
  Fault Module Timestamp: 5d6aa558
  Exception Code: c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_D7_FROM_ntdll+0x0000000000090D0A
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:  1033
  Additional Information 1: 5374
  Additional Information 2: 5374ed43e735bef572e0bdf6cea33f50
  Additional Information 3: 1900
  Additional Information 4: 19003b848f83d262db1d6f52dffc6694

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

On Windows Server 2008, this crash happens as soon as I start the application.  I did install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable.

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: Test.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: f1a0272b
  Problem Signature 04: CefSharp.WinForms
  Problem Signature 05: 75.1.143.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5dbe3f2d
  Problem Signature 07: 58
  Problem Signature 08: 22
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException
  OS Version:   6.0.6003.2.2.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

When I copy the entire `bin\x64\release` folder onto my Windows Server 2012 computer, the application works correctly.

However, when I copy the entire `bin\x64\release` onto my Windows Server 2008 computer, the application fails with the same error.  The error is referencing `CefSharp.WinForms`, even though `cefsharp.winforms.dll` is in that folder.

[image]

So my questions:

- Why is the ClickOnce installation failing on Windows 2008 and partially failing on Windows 2012?  It looks like ClickOnce prerequisites in Visual Studio are configured to install all the necessary CefSharp files.
- Why does copying my entire `bin\x64\release` directory not work on my Windows 2008 computer?

Comment: Are you using `Windows 2008` or `Windows 2008r2`? `Chrome` removed support for `Windows 2008` quite some time ago, see the `Notes` section of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v75.1.141

Comment: Also please no images of error message, copy and paste the whole error please.

Comment: @amaitland It's Windows 2008 (not R2).  Thanks for the information that CefSharp no longer works on that.  I'll stop testing on that computer.  I updated the original question with the text of the error messages instead of screenshots.

Comment: If copying the bin folder works then it's likely a resource is missing, probably a bin or pak file. Check the clockonce folder after you have installed your app.