# Deploy the CEF Redistributables in my CEFSharp Deployment Project

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, cefsharp

I have a project that uses CEFSharp and I am using a windows deployment project to create a setup.  When I compile the program, during the build process, it copies the .pak files and creates the "locales" folder in the debug/release folder as found here.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Getting-Started

I can add the .pak files as dependencies, but is there a way to create the "locales" folder and copy the appropriate files there?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1314
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841585/deploying-wpf-application-with-3rd-party-dlls/24287807#24287807

Comment: Thanks.  That shed some light on it.  I am not familiar with MSBUILD so it was a bit above my head.  I wound up copying everything from the "release" folder to the install folder on the target machine.  This works.  The only time it breaks is when I update CEFSharp, then another copy and I am good to go.