# Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Code.DDL

Tags: filenotfoundexception, cefsharp

There are thousands of posts on the Internet related to this bug, but none of them have worked for me. Above, there are some approaches that I have tried:

- [Copy dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841585/deploying-wpf-application-with-3rd-party-dlls/24287807#24287807);
- Double check references;
- Install VC++ 2012 and 2013;
- and so on.

I am trying to use CefSharp in an Outlook Add-on Project. My environment is setup for 64 bit. When I execute the CefSharp.MinimalExemple, everything works fine.

My app throws ***Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found*** as soon as the followed line is reached:
`CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");`

[Also, I have checked the dependencies using Dependency Walker. The result was the same for my project and the MinimalExemple that works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioZEb.png)

I am sure I am missing some silly thing, but I am not being able to see it by myself. My guessing is that the bug is related to the 32/64 environment. But I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1191

Comment: https://github.com/stever/AppHostCefSharp

Comment: Thanks, @amaitland... AppHostCefSharp would be a very good trying. At this moment, I am doing some tests with DotNetBrowser. Although it costs money, it may worth because in 10 minutes the system worked like a charm.

Comment: Use whatever browser works