# Installing Universal CRT for CefSharp application release

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, runtime, visual-c++-runtime

I'm trying to create an application that uses CefSharp and installs the C++ Runtime automatically. I found a great article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841585/deploying-wpf-application-with-3rd-party-dlls). (But it's outdated, since i'm using visual studio 2015 and a newer cefsharp version 57.0.0).
However I this is an older version of visual studio and since then they released a new way of adding Runtime Files (as said in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) article).

I found another article explaining where to find the DLL's that I need to import [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805113/visual-studio-2015-run-time-dependencies-or-how-to-get-rid-of-universal-crt/35806815#35806815), yet I still can't run my application (and I think it's because i'm missing a reference to them).
This is what I got in my post-build event command line:

> xcopy "$(SolutionDir)packages\CefSharp.Wpf.57.0.0\cef*" "$(TargetDir)"
>   /s /y /i

And this is where I put all of the DLL's i could find.
[image: My DDL's and their folder]

Comment: it maybe some need registering

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: some DLLs have to be registered - so the classes contained within are known to windows and it then goes off to find the DLL based on that  - lookup regsrv and registering DLLs