# ClickOnce stops silently after "Verifying application requirements. This may take a few moments"

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, clickonce

I upgraded the.Net Framework of a WPF application that I support from 4.5 to 4.5.2 and published the application. I also included.Net Framework 4.5.2 and Windows Installer 4.5 with the setup by following the instruction from the link below and some other articles on the internet.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

However, after users go to the install URL and install the application on the latest version of Windows 10(version 1709) and try to run the app, the app stops silently after showing this "Verifying application requirements. This may take a few moments" message for couple seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending much time tearing my hair, finally found the solution to this issue. The reason the app was crashing before it even got started is that because Visual C++ 2013 re-distributable was missing from the deployment package.
Below are the two articles that helped me solve this issue.

[Deploying WPF Application with 3rd Party DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841585/deploying-wpf-application-with-3rd-party-dlls)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1058700/Embedding-Chrome-in-your-Csharp-App-using-CefSharp