# What Visual C++ Runtimes are users likely to have installed?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, runtime, msvcrt

### What Visual C++ Runtimes are users likely to have installed?

**Update:** This question has become more of a "What is the best way to deploy internet based applications, written in C++. That require the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime."

Comment: I don't know if there is a definitive answer to this question, because I believe that what is included changes based on the SP level of the OS, or perhaps even more frequently than that. And I know you've said "fully patched", but that sort of confuses the issue - if it is truly "fully patched", wouldn't that mean the answer to your question is "what ever the current version is"? (I believe that the VC++ redis often comes as an optional update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is important because of the needs of *internet deployment* of C++ based applications.

---

I have found the following:

- No fresh Windows installation comes any C++ runtime (except msvcrt.dll)
- Windows XP and higher ship with .NET framework runtimes (which is not suitable)
- The C++ runtime redistributables are small downloads (1-4MB apiece)
- Automatic update does not install any C++ runtimes.
- When a runtime is installed. Windows handles security patches as long as Microsoft Update is enabled and it is deployed using the redistributable installer.
- Internet Deployment: Your installer (statically linked) should detect the presence of the runtime and download if not already installed. *You can also use the gcc-mingw32 compiler which uses the VC 6 runtime.* An internet connection is required for this approach.
- Most major apps do *not* appear to statically link. But some, like Mozilla Firefox distribute custom runtimes as a DLL.

Microsoft should start including the C++ runtimes with their OSes like they do for .NET

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe Microsoft makes any guarantees on which run times are available on an OS install.  It is more of a side effect of which included applications where build using the specific run time.

If you need a specific C++ run time you need to install it yourself.  If you are building an MSI install Visual Studio will have installed the required merge modules.  If not you can [download the run time](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.

If you want to be able install by just copying a single EXE, then statically link with the run time.  The run time will be built into your EXE and there will not be an external dependency.

Edit: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073509/should-i-redistribute-msvcrt-dll-with-my-application/1073916#1073916) -> Microsoft explicitly does not guarantee any version of the C++ run time will be installed on Windows at all.

Answer (score 2):

if it is a redistributable, then it is intended to be redistributed in an installer. I would include it as a "install if not already present" item in your installer.

As to the specific question you ask, have you tried the Microsoft website? It might take a bit of searching but it should be there.

Comment: The Express Edition seems to include a `redist.txt` that's pretty much identical to the one that comes with the other editions. The license agreement specifically says the (object form of) files listed in redist.txt are distributables.