# MT or MD for static release?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In the static release of my application, I do not want the user to need the msvcrt runtime. My application depends on another library that I compile myself. Should this library use multithreaded or multithreaded DLL when compiling it? The library is static compiled.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073509/should-i-redistribute-msvcrt-dll-with-my-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC++'s license agreement prohibits the distribution of debug builds on any computer that doesn't already have VC++ installed, so your only option is to use `/MTd` or `/MDd` for debug builds while developing the application and `/MT` for the release build meant for distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You should use DLL CRTs wherever possible, you can end up with trouble if you start linking multiple copies statically. If you know for a fact that you're compiling the final product, then you could link statically.