# Deploying Qt with MinGW requires VC++ redistributable?

Tags: qt, deployment

I'm testing an application using Qt 4.7.3 compiled with MinGW on a clean XP virtual box.  The application wasn't working and after much grief, I traced the error to needing to download the Visual C++ 2005 redistributable.  I downloaded this and it worked.  Something doesn't seem right here, shouldn't I not need any VC++ libraries since I'm using MinGW?  Could it be a problem with my compilation?  I should mention that I'm not using qmake to build.

Comment: How do you think Qt interfaces with windows, magic? ;)

Comment: We have had same problem with qt 5.0.1 but the problem wasn't in msvcrt. Standard qt application also requires libEGL.dll from qt mingw folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependency on `MSVCRT.DLL` is due to MinGW itself. To quote mingw.org..

> MinGW provides a complete Open Source programming tool set which is
>   suitable for the development of native MS-Windows applications, and
>   which do not depend on any 3rd-party C-Runtime DLLs. (It does depend
>   on a number of DLLs provided by Microsoft themselves, as components of
>   the operating system; most notable among these is MSVCRT.DLL, the
>   Microsoft C runtime library.

Also see: [Should I redistribute msvcrt.dll with my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073509/31044)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the Qt documentation, yes, that is required:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: I had read through that (mostly) - perhaps I need to read it more thoroughly.  It sounds to me like they are saying the VC++ libs are needed only when compiling with Visual Studio.