# What is the difference between 7z.sfx and 7zsd.sfx modules in 7zip?

Tags: c#, java, windows, file, zip

What is the difference between the `7z.sfx` and `7zsd.sfx` modules in 7zip?

Comment: I answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087595/what-is-the-difference-between-7zips-7z-sfx-and-7zsd-sfx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`7z.sfx` is the Windows version.

`7zSD.sfx` is the Windows version for installers (uses `MSVCRT.dll`).

Comment: @Sigalit 7zS.sfx is just the regular Windows version for installers (doesn't use MSVCRT.dll).