# 7zS.sfx does not exist in the 7-Zip folder

Tags: sfx

I want to use the sfx module to create a .exe file of an installer

On reading up online i found that we need this particular file : 7zS.sfx
According to the instructions [here](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/izpack/#sfx)

this particular file should be available in 7-Zip folder (program files or where it has been installed). 
The problem is I cannot find this file. I tried downloading 7-zip again. Still not able to see this file.

Is there any extra plug-in i need to download for this file?

Comment: You can find this modules into LZMA SDK on official website https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

Well after reading up a bit more about the types of sfx modules available... as specified by this [SO-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087595/what-is-the-difference-between-7zips-7z-sfx-and-7zsd-sfx)  ...I downloaded the 7z_extra module from [here](http://code.google.com/p/7-zip/downloads/detail?name=7z-extra-920.7z)

The installer works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find the files `7zS2.sfx` `7zSD.sfx` in the LZMA packages (bin folder) in the [LZMA SDK](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), for example [lzma1604](https://www.7-zip.org/a/lzma1900.7z).

As a further **NOTE**:

`7zS2.sfx` finds the `setup.exe` or the first exe file in the package and runs it.

`7zSD.sfx` uses `config.txt` as described [here](http://richardbalsley.com/how-to-create-a-silent-self-extracting-installer-for-use-with-windows-configuration-designer)