# Use your own msvcrt.dll instead of the system32 one

Tags: windows, dll, msvcrt

I have a cpp program with some dependencies dll (black box for me). One of this dll depend on the MSVCRT.dll of windows/system32/.

My program run on win vista and newer but doesn't on win xp cause the msvcrt.dll is too old and don't have some functions.

I'd like to use my own msvcrt.dll (which come from win Vista) with my program but i don't know to tell this to the dependent dll (i don't have the sources of it) which requires msvcrt.

Thanks !

-- test -- 
I joined a newer msvcrt.dll in the folder containing my app (a .dll in fact), dependy walker tell me that it's still linking to the system32/msvcrt.dll

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I redistribute msvcrt.dll with my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073509/should-i-redistribute-msvcrt-dll-with-my-application)

Comment: Yep, this question ask Should i. I'm concern by "how redistribute msvcrt with my application"

Comment: See "DLL Search order": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your answers where right, thank you!

To my particlar problem it was my version of minGw. The last releases of minGW can't compile code for windows xp. It compiles but not run due to a problem with the MSVCRT.dll dependencies.

It seems to be a bug and there are issues on it, so hope that it will be solve in the coming months.